# Store QPointer into a QVariant

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant, qpointer

Can I store a `QPointer`, for example a `QPointer<QTcpSocket>` inside a `QVariant` and later extract it from it?

I tried with:

```
    QObject *ob = new QObject();
    QPointer<QObject> qp(ob);
    QVariant qv(qp);
```

But I got an error - `QVariant::QVariant(void*)' is private`.

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, it is possible by using `QVariant::fromValue()` and `QVariant::value()`.

Example code:

```
    QTcpSocket *ob = new QTcpSocket();
    qDebug("%p", ob);
    QPointer<QTcpSocket> qp(ob);
    QVariant qv = QVariant::fromValue(qp);
    qp = qv.value<QPointer<QTcpSocket> >();
    qDebug("%p", qp.data());
    delete ob;
    qDebug("%p", qp.data());
```

This gives:

```
0x137c070
0x137c070
0x0
```